# Async function wrapped in promise vs. sync function

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous

So I've always wondered if there is any benefit to this. I'll give examples below.

Asynchronous function wrapped in a Promise:

```
(async () => {
    await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fs.writeFile(filePath, dataToWrite, (error) => {
            if (error) {
                reject(error);
                return;
            }
            resolve();
        });
    });
})();
```

Synchronous function:

```
(() => {
    fs.writeFileSync(filePath, dataToWrite);
})();
```

The only thing I know from light reading is that the synchronous function call blocks the process until done. So for example a web server with api endpoints will not be able to process those requests until the synchronous function is done. Is this also true for the asynchronous function wrapped in a promise? If there are any differences between the two and could one give an explanation if so?

Comment: async function itself returns a promise which is non blocking

Comment: Well given that there is no code anywhere in your example that waits for anything, it does not make a difference at all. Also why wrap it in an IIFE at all?

Comment: If I'm not wrong, writeFileSync is blocking and you must wait until it has finished to write the file on the disk/filesystem.

Comment: and also if you're working with arrays of Promises.
instead of loop on the array using the `await` it's better to use Promise.all();
since `await` blocks the async function execution while Promise.all() run them in parallel.

Comment: @Bergi Hence the reason why I mentioned an api. Imagine that I have code in my application that is waiting for http requests. Let's say the function above it executed and while the function is running a http request comes in. Does the function block everything until done? Or does it handle the request *and* the fucntion at the same time (no blocking).

Comment: Instead of wrapping a callback async function inside a promise manually, I would rather use [promisify](https://nodejs.org/api/util.html#util_util_promisify_original)

Answer (score 3):

> The synchronous function call blocks the process until done.

Yes.

> Is this also true for the asynchronous function wrapped in a promise?

No, that's the point of asynchronous processing.

The `await` only "blocks" the execution of the code of the particular `async function` until the awaited promise settles, but everything else will continue running.

Comment: So it *is* beneficial to to wrap a async function in a promise if you wish for other parts of the application to not be blocked while the function is being run? (Just want to clarify)

Comment: Wrapping in a promise is a good practice but not the reason that it's non-blocking. It's about using an asynchronous function - `writeFile` instead of `writeFileSync` - in the first place. Promises and `async function` just make dealing with the result easier than using callbacks.